# Why is gauge-transformed four-potential a covariant vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

In a static system, gauge transformation is this.

$\tilde{\boldsymbol{A}} = \boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \chi \ \ \ (1)\\
\tilde{\phi} = \phi - \partial _t \chi\ \ \ (2)$

If you gather these equations into one equation, it becomes

$\tilde{A} _\mu = A _\mu + \partial _\mu \chi.\ \ \ (3)$

Now, according to my teacher, $\tilde{A} _\mu$ is a covariant vector. But why?

The scalar potential $\phi$ and the vector potential $\boldsymbol{A}$ are defined as followed. (Please note that $\boldsymbol{E}, \boldsymbol{B}$ here are static fields.)

$\boldsymbol{E} = - \boldsymbol{\nabla} \phi\ \ \ (4) \\
\boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{A}\ \ \ (5)$

eq.(1) satisfies eq.(5), so the space components of $A_\mu$ are one of the vector potentials. However, eq.(2) doesn't satisfy eq.(4), so the time component multiplied by c isn't one of the scalar potentials.

Thus, I believe $\tilde{A} _\mu$ and $A_\mu$ don't have the same property.

---

If $\chi$ is a scalar, which satisfies $\chi = \chi '$, I can understand $\tilde{A} _\mu$ is a covariant vector by comparing the left-hand side of eq.(3) with right-hand side of it. But, anyway, I don't come up with the reason why $\chi$ is a scalar.

Comment: 1. Eq. (4) only holds for static potentials. If you make a general gauge transformation, the potentials don't need to be static anymore. 2. What "reason" do you want for $\chi$ to be a scalar other than that it's a real-valued function. It's evidently not a vector, and there's no reason in sight it should transform under Lorentz transformations in any other way than a scalar field. One might say that a gauge transformation $\chi$ is *by definition* a scalar, so I'm a bit confused what you actually want to know here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you very much. I misunderstood the definition of electromagnetic potentials. Now I checked my notebook and understand the true definition for non-static fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your definition of the electrical field is not correct. Electrical field is not only generated by a conservative potential $\phi$, but also through induction quantified by Faraday's law. So the vector potential (if non-zero) contributes to the electrical field: 
${\bf E} = -\nabla \phi -\frac{\partial {\bf A}}{\partial t}$

Taking this definition into account the field $\chi$ will cancel out in the 
expression of ${\bf E}$ as it should be in order to guarantee the gauge invariance of the el. and mag. field strength.
And finally $\bf A_\mu$ and $\bf \tilde{A}_\mu$ $\mu=0,\ldots,3$ behave exactly the same way.

As a side remark, a betatron uses the electrical field generated by a changing magnetic field (${\bf A\neq 0}$, but $\phi=0$) to accelerate charged particles. A pure magnetic field would not be able to do it. A bit a pity that these machines are practically extinct as they demonstrate so well the contribution of the vector potential $\bf A$ to $\bf E$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood the definition of electromagnetic potentials. Now I checked my notebook and understand the true definition for non-static fields.

Comment: I do not feel that you answered the question. How come the four-potential is a covariant four-vector?